# Trying to use jQuery .delay()

Tags: jquery

What am I doing wrong here? It looks like my .delay is not working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var imgsrc = "#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#spinner_big.gif";

    $('a#add-node').click(function() {
        $('a#add-node').hide();
        $('#form-loading').show().delay(5000);
        $('#form-loading').hide()
        $('a#add-node').show();
    });
});
```

I basically would like to display my form-loading div, wait 5 seconds, then hide it and then display my other add-node div.

When I press on my button, noting seems to happen, it just shows my original add-node div button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
   $('#form-loading').show().delay(5000);
   $('#form-loading').hide();
```

you should do

```
   $('#form-loading').show().delay(5000).hide();
```

Taken from documentation:

> The .delay() method is best for
>   delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects.

Anyway if nothing happens, it seems like your event is not attached correctly. Post the markup to or a fiddle so that we can help

EDIT - i read the documentation a little better:

> Added to jQuery in version 1.4, the
>   .delay() method allows us to delay the
>   execution of functions that follow it
>   in the queue. It can be used with the
>   standard effects queue or with a
>   custom queue. Only subsequent events
>   in a queue are delayed; for example
>   this will not delay the no-arguments
>   forms of .show() or .hide() which do
>   not use the effects queue.

So you cant use delay with show() and hide(); The you have to use setTimeout() i guess:

```
$('a#add-node').click(function() {
    $('a#add-node').hide();
    $('#form-loading').show();
    setTimeout(restoreVisibility, 5000);
});

var restoreVisibility = function(){
    $('#form-loading').hide();
    $('a#add-node').show();
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qUD7U/1/

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately I couldn't get it working. Could you possibly provide a working example in jsFiddle for us, would really appreciate it. Could it be also that I am using IE8 causing me issues?

Comment: @tonsils if you provide your html i can try to fix it!

Comment: @tonsils you were right, it didn't work, i provided a new answer

Comment: thanks for the new answer and fiddle as I knew something wasn't right with .delay and show/hide.